# pattern matches no files

Tags: go, go-templates, go-gin

My webapp structure:

```
- gin-cource
   - src
   - templates
      - tmpl1
          file.html
          *.html
      - tmpl2
          file.html
          *.html
```

When I run it I get the panik

```
html/template: pattern matches no files: `templates/**/*.html` 
... 
c:/users/user/go/src/gin-course/src/main.go:11 +0x50
```

The code:

```
r := gin.Default()
r.LoadHTMLGlob("templates/**/*.html") // line 11
```

I've tried different paths to templates in the go code: `"/templates/**/*.html", "src/templates/**/*.html" "gin-cource/src/templates/**/*.html"`
But they were not suited.

What is the right path to templates?

Comment: Looking at the error I can see your main.go file is inside src. It seems the templates dir is not inside src though. You should use the following path then: `../templates/**/*.html` or move `templates` in `src`. Relative path are relative to the place where the you run the program from.

Comment: @FrançoisP. that works. Did I undestand it rigth that the relative path calculates from the `main.go` file?

Comment: yes, it's correct.